# How can I apply filters on Table based on dropdown Value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have one dropdown with values as

```html
<select ng-model="recat"  ng-options="r.Id as r.Name for r in Categories">
    <option value="" disabled="" class="">-- Select Category --</option>
    <option label="All" value="string:0" selected="selected">All</option>
    <option label="TAB" value="string:1">MALE</option>
    <option label="Project" value="string:2">Fe-Male</option>
</select>
```

My Table as

```html
<tr ng-repeat="r in rabanalysisreport | filter:recat">
    <!-- SomeData -->
</tr>
```

Here my problem is when I select **All**(0) I want to display **both** Male And Female Record. But Here Showing Only Male or Female

Comment: Please show `recat` filter. Do you use this filter somewhere else or just here?

Answer (score 0):

Create the custom filter method in scope.
Like:

```
$scope.customFilter = function( criteria ) {
  return function( item ) {
    if (criteria === '0') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return item.recat === criteria;
    }
  };
};
```

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in rabanalysisreport | customFilter(recat)">
    <!-- SomeData -->
</tr>
```

If you provide an example of your data can do more detailed code